# Complex query is not working with Entity Framework ";WITH"

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server

I am working with multi-level marketing application, with Entity Framework. I have create a stored procedure but somehow the query shown below is not working - why?

```
;WITH OrgTree ([GenealogyTreeID], [MemberRegisterId], [ParentMemberRegisterId], Level) AS
(
    SELECT 
        [GenealogyTreeID], [MemberRegisterId],
        [ParentMemberRegisterId], 0 AS Level 
    FROM 
        GenealogyTree 
    WHERE 
        ParentMemberRegisterId IS NULL --= 'c9f8479f-2bad-4a70-9c0c-e5c9c6bb1e26'

    UNION ALL

    SELECT 
        g.[GenealogyTreeID], g.[MemberRegisterId],
        g.[ParentMemberRegisterId], OrgTree.Level + 1 
    FROM 
        GenealogyTree g
    JOIN 
        OrgTree ON g.ParentMemberRegisterId = OrgTree.MemberRegisterId
)
SELECT DISTINCT
    g.GenealogyTreeID, g.MemberRegisterId,  
    CASE 
       WHEN g.Level = 0 THEN NULL
       ELSE g.ParentMemberRegisterId 
    END AS ParentMemberRegisterId,  
    g.Level, 
    ISNULL((mmr.FirstName + ' ' + mmr.MiddleName + ' ' + mmr.LastName),
    (mr.FirstName + ' ' + mr.MiddleName + ' ' + mr.LastName)) as ParentFullName,
    (mr.FirstName + ' ' + mr.MiddleName + ' ' + mr.LastName) as SelFullName,
    mr.photo
FROM
    OrgTree g 
INNER JOIN 
    MemberRegister mr on mr.MemberRegisterId = g.MemberRegisterId
INNER JOIN 
    MemberRegister mmr on mmr.MemberRegisterId = g.ParentMemberRegisterId 
WHERE
    mr.FirstName LIKE '%'+ @SearchValue +'%' 
    OR mr.MiddleName LIKE '%'+ @SearchValue +'%' 
    OR mr.LastName LIKE '%'+ @SearchValue +'%'
    OR mmr.FirstName LIKE '%'+ @SearchValue +'%' 
    OR mmr.MiddleName LIKE '%'+ @SearchValue +'%' 
    OR mmr.LastName LIKE '%'+ @SearchValue +'%' 
ORDER BY
    ParentMemberRegisterId
    OFFSET @PageSize * (@PageNo - 1) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT @PageSize ROWS ONLY
    OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Comment: You didn't mention the issue you are facing. Plus there is no table structure to look into. It is highly recommended to share whatever info you can.

Comment: i have mention error in comment

Answer (score 0):

You should remove first `;`

```
WITH OrgTree
  ...
;
```

Otherwise ORM would get first statement as empty one and ignore the second.

`;WITH` pattern is used because `;` is not mandatory in general in T-SQL but a few statements require it like CTE/MERGE. This is why some developers start `WITH` with `;`

Comment: i have removed ; and try but not resolve; it show me below error.

A system assertion check has failed. Check the SQL Server error log for details. Typically, an assertion failure is caused by a software bug or data corruption. To check for database corruption, consider running DBCC CHECKDB. If you agreed to send dumps to Microsoft during setup, a mini dump will be sent to Microsoft. An update might be available from Microsoft in the latest Service Pack or in a QFE from Technical Support. 
A severe error occurred on the current command.  The results, if any, should be discarded.

Comment: @BhaveshThummar Well the error message is clear,  some of your files are corrupted. You should run DBCC CHECKDB and most likely you will need to restore DB from last "good" backup. It  is nothing related to EF/C# but DB itself.

Comment: i have already trying this command and if i just change to normal query then it's working find.